# Solspace Freeform: Looping through Radio group options in template

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

Using Solspace Freeform, I am trying to hardcode a radio gorup and its options in to a template. My effort is below but its not working

```
{# get the radio group field #}
{% set interestedIn = form.get("interestedIn") %}
{# Loop through the radio options #}                        
{% for option in interestedIn %}
<input type="radio" id="form-input-{{ interestedIn.handle }}" name="{{ interestedIn.handle }}" value="email">
<label for="form-input-{{ interestedIn.handle }}">Email</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manually generate multi-option fields like radios, your code would look something like this:

```
{% set yourFieldHandle = form.get("yourFieldHandle") %}

<label>{{ yourFieldHandle.label }}</label>
{% for option in yourFieldHandle.options %}
   <div class="radio">
      <label>
         <input type="radio" name="yourFieldHandle" value="{{ option.value }}" {{ option.checked ? "checked" }} />
         {{ option.label|raw }}
      </label>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```